# How can I make R import each line of a .txt file as a character string?

Tags: r, txt

I have a complex .txt file, of which I'll add a screenshot [.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmqT.png). I need to have each line as its own character string in order to group the lines of code by the 5 letter code near the beginning of each line (group together all GPGGA lines, for example; see screenshot) in order to process it as I need to. Here's what I've run so far:

```
df <- data.frame(Weather_data)
df %>%
  mutate("Entry" = gsub(".*\\$([A-Z]+),.*", "\\1", text)) %>%
  group_by(Entry) %>%
  filter(Entry == "GPGGA")
```

This received the error:

"Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Entry`. i `Entry = gsub(".*\\$([A-Z]+),.*", "\\1", text)`. x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

I had success filtering as I needed to when I copied and pasted the first few lines in and manually made then character strings to see if I could get the code to function, so making each line a character string NOT manually (there are over 3000 lines) is the next step. Anyone have a function to do this?

Here are some of the lines produced when I load the imported txt file:

```
HEADER
<chr>
13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68
13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72
13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E
13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG,74.8,0.0,E,3.6,W*6E
13:30:01.003: <- $WIMDA,29.9641,I,1.0147,B,26.5,C,,,48.2,,14.6,C,323.0,T,326.6,M,1.4,N,0.7,M*66
13:30:01.051: <- $WIMWV,248.4,R,1.1,N,A*29
13:30:01.114: <- $WIMWV,255.6,T,1.3,N,A*23
13:30:01.195: <- $YXXDR,A,-53.9,D,PTCH,A,-34.2,D,ROLL*57
13:30:01.307: <- $YXXDR,A,0.571,G,XACC,A,0.783,G,YACC,A,-0.181,G,ZACC*57
13:30:01.578: <- $GPGGA,183001.30,4415.6242,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.9,M,-33.4,M,,*64
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your twt files once imported please? You can use `dput` for it

Comment: I've updated the original to include a snippet at the end. There are 9 repeating codes that were run by a weather instrument, each with a different 5 letter signature (Like the GPGGA), and I am trying to sort the data by that classification

Comment: Do you want to use `HEADER` instead of `text` ? Also you don't need `group_by(Entry)` here to `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You referenced the variable `text` which does not exist in your data.frame. Your column is named `HEADER`.

```
df %>%
  mutate("Entry" = gsub(".*\\$([A-Z]+),.*", "\\1", HEADER)) %>%
  group_by(Entry) %>%
  filter(Entry == "GPGGA")
```

Comment: @Seanie_13 did this solution work for you?